# Change displayed name for column ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What I want to do is display the value "Closed" or "Open" in the view based on the value in the database which is 1=Open and 0=Closed. I have tried this way in the ViewModel:

```
    public int Closed 
    {
        get
        {
            string x = ReturnString;
            int y = Int32.Parse(x);
            return y;
        }
        set
        { }
    }

    public string ReturnString
    {
        get
        {
            if (Closed.ToString().Equals("1"))
            {
                return "Closed";
            }
            else (Closed.ToString().Equals("0"))
            {
                return "Open";
            }
        }
        set { }    
    }
```

And this is my View:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Bdgfixmonths)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Closed)
        </td>
    }
</tbody>
```

What I have to do in the Controller to display the value Open/Closed instead of 0/1? 
Also how do I access the variable of the ViewModel in the table instead of the one in the Model?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use ENUM:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebAppTest1.Pages
{
    public class DoorModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<Door> doors;
        public void OnGet()
        {
            doors = new List<Door>();
            doors.Add(new Door { DoorID = 1, DoorStatus = DoorStatuses.Open });
            doors.Add(new Door { DoorID = 2, DoorStatus = DoorStatuses.Closed });
            doors.Add(new Door { DoorID = 3, DoorStatus = DoorStatuses.Open });
            doors.Add(new Door { DoorID = 4, DoorStatus = DoorStatuses.Closed });
        }
    }

    public class Door
    {
        public int DoorID { get; set; }
        public DoorStatuses DoorStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public enum DoorStatuses
    {
        [Display(Name = "Open")]
        Open = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Closed")]
        Closed = 0
    }

    //Utility function to show ENUM display value
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
        {
            return enumValue.GetType()
                            .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                            .First()
                            .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                            .GetName();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@page
@model WebAppTest1.Pages.DoorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Door";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Demo to show ENUM display name</h1>
<div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Door ID</div>
        <div class="col-4">Status ID</div>
        <div class="col-4">Status</div>
    </div>

    @foreach (var door in Model.doors)
    {
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">@door.DoorID</div>
            <div class="col-4">@door.DoorStatus</div>
            <div class="col-4">@door.DoorStatus.GetDisplayName()</div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, seems a very excellent solution. The problem now is if I put your code in the model, it throws an exception when I run the project: "SqlException: Invalid column name 'ClosedStatus'.", and if I put it in the ViewModel, in the view says: "'Bdgfixmonth' does not contain a definition for 'ClosedStatus' and no accessible extension method 'ClosedStatus' accepting a first argument of type 'Bdgfixmonth' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)."

Comment: check the latest code, I just copied from my working sample on Visual Studio. You need to modify the code according to your need, I need to change the class names, property according to the column name. Try this code in fresh project first instead of your existing solution, then you will have an understanding on where to change in your code. you need to following namespaces:

Comment: you need to add following namespaces: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

Comment: Before assigning database values (0, 1) to the ENUM type property you need to convert the values like following: 
            doors.Add(new Door { DoorID = 4, DoorStatus = (DoorStatuses)0 });

Answer (score 0):

Use if

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Bdgfixmonths)
    {
       if(item.Closed==1){
           <td>
               ...
           </td>
       }
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: @chdev you r welcome